# Does unity make all operations before the frame ends?

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame

Suppose we just started the frame `f1` and the next frame is `f2`.

Will `f1` wait Unity to do all operations in `Update()`, `LateUpdate()` and `FixedUpdate()` before it starts `f2` or `f1` has a time to run and when the time is done, it just skip the left operations and start `f2` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

As I can read [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) seems like `FixedUpdate` can be overloaded, cause it has a "fixed" time, which can possible cause methods to be cutted in the middle of the execution.

But the rest of the methods are called once per frame, so the frame should wait.